# Do I create animations in a game engine (such as Godot) or in Blender after I have rigged a game character in Blender?

Tags: animation, game-engine, export

If I rigged a game character using Blender, after that do i have to create the animations in Blender and then export it to Godot or do I first export the character to Godot then I can create the animations in Godot?

Comment: I suggest to ask that at a godot forum

Comment: You should be able to do either, I expect you will find doing the animation easier in blender.